# Online site to easily generate stats on census data

Tags: references

If I wanted to answer the following question, is there any website which will allow me to do it? (or has it already been done?)

What percentage of people with Computer Science Degrees aged 30-40 are Married?
  What percentage of people with other degrees aged 30-40 are Married?

Surely somewhere online there is a site where I can put criteria like that in and generate basic results?

Comment: In the US, the official site is http://factfinder2.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml

Comment: For info on census / IPUMS, see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27062/3748

Answer (score 2):

Re: "Census data" (US decennial census and CPS), follow whuber's link.  For your example questions, there are some other census (lower-case "c") datasets/website.

Datasets: the [NSCG](http://www.nsf.gov/statistics/srvygrads/) has both college major & marital status. The [SDR](http://www.nsf.gov/statistics/srvydoctoratework/) has doctorate data.

Website: visit [SESTAT](https://sestat.nsf.gov/sestat/sestat.html), use NSCG 2003, pick W_DEM_MARITAL_STATUS plus education variables plus set condition that U_DEM_AGE>=30 and <=40, and it generates a table on the spot.

Also: [typing your first question into Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=What+percentage+of+people+with+Computer+Science+Degrees+aged+30-40+are+Married%3F+), "Result: -10".

Comment: SESTAT seems really cool!  It was able to answer my question very easily, and was exactly what I was after.  Thankyou.