# How is research based on the U.S. Census organized?

Tags: census

As I understand, most of the research is centralized through the U.S. Census Bureau. However, I couldn't find any overview of fields of research on their website. Is there any other institution or website that summarizes the research that has been done?

I'd especially like to know which data is of most interest to researchers but everything seems to be so restricted and it is hard to find a collection of publications regarding research outcomes based on the census.

I appreciate any advise or direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IPUMS](http://usa.ipums.org/usa/) from the University of Minnesota makes Census data easily available to researchers with few restrictions. A bibliography for the use of this particular source is available [here](http://bibliography.ipums.org/).

Of course, this is only one point of access for Census data, the bibliography is based on self-reporting, and this only counts research using the publicly-available data from the Census, but hopefully this is a good start.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I indeed stumbled upon the IPUMS but failed to grasp its importance. Further, I am not interested in the Census data itself but rather in the research that has been done with that data. I would think of it as a meta level where I want to summarize the research. Would you say IPUMS is one of the largest access points (how many are there roughly?)? If so, could IPUMS be a representation of all access points and thus hold a representative collection of research papers?

Comment: The bibliography gives the research projects that have used IPUMS. The terms of service state that you have to report your project to them, but I don't know what the compliance is actually like. Getting Census data from the Bureau directly leads to a data set that is hard to corral with formats that vary across years. IPUMS is the easiest way to get the data in a useable form. As a result, I would guess that many researchers do indeed use this source.