# What are the most useful sources of economics data?

Tags: references

When doing research in Economy, one frequently needs to verify theoretical conclusions on real data. What are reliable data sources to use and cite? I am mainly interested in sources that provide various statistical data such as GDP, population, CPI, PPI etc.

**EDIT:**
Here's an aggregation of the links appearing in this thread + a few more I remembered.
**Generic:**
 - [Thomson Reuters Datastream](http://thomsonreuters.com/) (not free, very comprehensive)
 - [World Bank Data](http://data.worldbank.org)
 - [United Nations Data](http://data.un.org/)
 - [IMF Data](http://www.imf.org/external/data.htm)
 - [ADB Data](http://www.adb.org/statistics)
 - [WTO Stats](http://www.adb.org/statistics)
 - [Infochimps](http://www.infochimps.com/) - massive resource of a wide variety of public and private (commercial) datasources - plus their [API](http://www.infochimps.com/apis)
 - [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/) (now owned by Google) - open data resource
 - [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/About) - an approach to using the Wikipedia API
 - [Wikipedia API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) - or go direct and access Wikipedia direct
 - [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/index.html)
 - [OECD Statistics](http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx)
 - [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) - a knowledge search engine
 - [Zanran](http://www.zanran.com/q/) - a numerical & statistics search engine
 - [Inter-university Consortium for Political and Social Research](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/)

**National:**
 - [UK government data project](http://data.gov.uk/)
 - [US government data project](http://www.data.gov/)
 - [US FRED: Federal Reserve Economic Data](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/)
 - [US Bureau of Labor Statistics](http://www.bls.gov/) 
 - [US Bureau of Economic Analysis](http://bea.gov/) 
 - [U.S. Census](http://www.census.gov/)
 - [US Health & Retirement Study](http://hrsonline.isr.umich.edu/)
 - [U.S. Centers for Disease Control](http://www.cdc.gov/DataStatistics/)
 - [U.S. Bureau of Transportation Statistics](http://www.bts.gov/)
 - [Eurostat's Databases](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/statistics/themes)

**Other:**
 - [OpenData Initiative at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_data)

Comment: we might want to turn this into a community wiki

Comment: Yes, I don't see the Community Wiki checkbox when I edit the question though

Comment: Only moderators can turn questions to community wiki. This was a change introduced to SE network, some time ago.

Comment: Quantitative finance SE has a [similar question](http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/141/1106) with some additional sources.

Comment: A lot of people mentioned census data, it'd be helpful for people to be aware of IPUMS.  Charlie wrote that up in this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27062/3748

Answer (score 14):

For the US:

[FRED: Federal Reserve Economic Data](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/) (the best) 
[Bureau of Labor Statistics](http://www.bls.gov/) 
[Bureau of Economic Analysis](http://bea.gov/) 
[U.S. Census](http://www.census.gov/)

Comment: +1 for FRED, it truly is one of the most useful sources of economic data (especially financial/macroeconomic)

Answer (score 5):

The [World Bank data API](http://data.worldbank.org/developers) is particularly good and I wish that more global and state-level organisations would release this much.  Here are a few more to complement @check123:

- [UK government data project](http://data.gov.uk/);
- [US government data project](http://www.data.gov/);
- [Infochimps](http://www.infochimps.com/) - massive resource of a wide variety of public and private (commercial) datasources - plus their [API](http://www.infochimps.com/apis);
- [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/) (now owned by Google) - open data resource;
- [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/About) - an approach to using the Wikipedia API;
- [Wikipedia API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) - or go direct and access Wikipedia direct;

And the lazy person's choice, there is the [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/index.html).  I find that the data is sometimes a bit wrong, but it is a useful place to get a rather plentiful overview.

This is an exciting area of development so expect many more data resources to come.  Follow the [Open Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_data) page at Wikipedia for regular updates.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what you've got already, there's http://www.zanran.com/q/ - a search-engine dedicated to numerical data

Comment: Good idea! Zanran search engine is particularly interesting for economic data searches. It is uniquely suited to numeric data **even if already embedded within spreadsheets, charts, databases** and not otherwise possible (or very difficult) to search for and find online.

Answer (score 4):

**Local/Foreign governments**:

- Data from Finance Ministry and its bodies
- Reserve Bank
- Official publication of annual accounts of the country

**Academic Sources**:

- Research papers and journals
- Internal archives of universities and institutions
- Dedicated policy and welfare research centers
- Theory/Text books often have further reference

**International Aggregates**:

- [World Bank Data](http://data.worldbank.org)
- [United Nations Data](http://data.un.org/)
- [IMF Data](http://www.imf.org/external/data.htm)
- [ADB Data](http://www.adb.org/statistics)
- [WTO Stats](http://www.adb.org/statistics)
- International NGO(s)
- Print publications from multilateral institutions (like above)

**Private Sources**:

- Research and surveys by local/national and international NGO(s)
- Publications and surveys from mass-media (newspapers, news channels, magazines etc)
- Research and surveys from private organizations (ex - AC Nielsen)
- Publications and reports from financial organizations like Banks, Credit Ratings etc.

Answer (score 4):

The [U.S. Census Bureau](http://www.census.gov) was one of the first government agencies to put data on the web. I still remember the elation I felt back in 1995 when I found out I could get up to date [CPS reports and data](http://www.census.gov/cps/) online instead of having to go through library shelves. They provide both summary tables and public use microdata.

Similarly, [U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics](http://www.bls.gov) and [U.S. Bureau of Economic Analysis) provide easy online access to both summary and detailed series. BLS's [National Longitudinal Surves](http://www.bls.gov/nls/) is used in a lot of empirical micro research.

[U.S. Bureau of Transportation Statistics](http://www.bts.gov/) has a lot of tables, but some of them are in quite inconvenient formats. E.g., statistics on boating accidents by the U.S. Coast Guard came in PDF files the last time I checked.

[U.S. Centers for Disease Control](http://www.cdc.gov/DataStatistics/) have an incredible wealth of data on both diseases and behavioral information. Among them is [Behavioral Risk Factor Surveillance System](http://www.cdc.gov/brfss/) which features prominently in health related research these days.

[Health & Retirement Study](http://hrsonline.isr.umich.edu/) "surveys a representative sample of more than 26,000 Americans over the age of 50 every two years."

Answer (score 2):

Rescued from a deleted answer:

If you are interested in the European Union or in some of its member states, you can have a look at [Eurostat's databases](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/statistics/themes).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/

Answer (score 1):

For macroeconomic and financial data, [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/) is a great resource, because it effectively acts as a wrapper around many of the excellent sources mentioned here, and many others.

What is more `library(Quandl)` makes accessing the data in `R` gratifyingly simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for free monthly global economic indicators to download, have a look at the database on the blog www.morethanbrics.com/blog. They publish a monthly database for up to 169 countries since 1995. I like it because you can download the whole excel file for free and it's updated on a monthly basis. It's based on Worldbank data and includes, among others, the following:

- Real GDP Growth
- CPI
- Core CPI
- Industrial Production
- Retail Sales
- Imports
- Exports
- Foreign Exchange Reserves
- Terms of Trade
- M2 Multiplier

Answer (score 0):

There are very related questions in the Economics and quant stacks:
https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/what-are-some-good-repositories-for-economic-data

https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online

Answers from there: The [American Economic Association has a list of resources for Economists, including a page for data](http://rfe.org/showCat.php?cat_id=2), there you find links to many institutions that offer all kinds of data, as well as further journals with data archives for the studies they publish.

In the [ReplicationWiki](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de) (that I work on) we have information on more than 2000 empirical studies and you can search for which one what kind of [data](http://preview.tinyurl.com/Replication-Wiki-Data), [software](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Category:Article_software_used), and [methods](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Category:Article_methods_and_estimation) were used, if the material is available, and if replications are known. Many studies can be browsed by [JEL codes](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Category:Article_JEL_codes) or [keywords](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Category:Article_keywords). The categorization of [data sources](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Category:Geographical_origin_of_data) and [geographical origin of data](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Category:Article_data_source) remains very incomplete but it is a wiki, so everyone can contribute and make suggestions.